# How can I separate the HTML Elements and the CSS elements and return them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a JS fiddle of one part I want to achieve.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aygcLftL/2/)

```
alert($("#content")[0].outerHTML);
```

This returns the DOM structure like:

```
 <div id="content">
     <div id="example1" style="width:100px height:100px background-color:red"></div>
     <div id="example2" style="width:50px height:50px background-color:blue"></div>
     <div id="example3" style="width:25px height:25px background-color:yellow"></div>
 </div>
```

I will be adding the `div`s dynamically and the CSS will be `inline`. Ideally, I want to be able to take the CSS out so I can return both the `div` elements and then the CSS attributes separately as text elements.

Comment: This isn't very clear, but if you want to remove the style **attribute**, you can do `$("#content").children().removeAttr('style')`

Comment: can you specify your required output with example?

Comment: I figured it out based on your line of code, thank you. I used
   `alert($("#content").children().attr("style"));`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove style attributes and store them in some id-style map, so you can use them later if you need. Something like this:

```js
var styles = {};

$("#content").children().each(function() {
    styles[this.id] = $(this).attr('style');
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});

// Check
alert(
    'HTML:\n\n' + 
    $("#content")[0].outerHTML + 
    '\n\nCSS:\n\n' + 
    JSON.stringify(styles, null, 4)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <div id="example1" style="width:100px height:100px background-color:red"></div>
    <div id="example2" style="width:50px height:50px background-color:blue"></div>
    <div id="example3" style="width:25px height:25px background-color:yellow"></div>
</div>
```